# From which Magento 1 version "catalogProductAttributeSetCreate" method is available

Tags: magento-1, soap, wsdl

From which Magento 1 version **catalogProductAttributeSetCreate** and **storeInfo** method is available for soap API.

Ex URL for soap wsdl:

https://demo.example.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1

https://demo.cart2quote.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1 -- 1.9

I'm using 1.11 EE and I've search "catalogProductAttributeSetCreate" in app\code\core folder it is not available.

Methods that I'm looking for is:

**catalogProductAttributeSetCreate** - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttributeSet/product_attribute_set.create.html

**storeInfo** - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/miscellaneous/store.info.html

August 8th 2011 Magento CE 1.6, PE 1.11, and EE 1.11 released

Reference for Magento release: https://sherocommerce.com/magento-history/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

catalogProductAttributeSetCreate and storeInfo methods are not available in SOAP API Magento-EE-1.11.00, and it's available from Magento EE 1.12.00 and Magento CE 1.6.1.0